# What does "to be doing" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

> **To be talking** about the dimensions of faithfulness as mediated by religious symbols is *to be doing* theology, not the practice itself.

(Source: [Robert C. Neville: The Truth of Broken Symbols](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rGvB-XGnqv4C&pg=PA252&dq=%22is%20to%20be%20doing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1fpMVcfoM8PB7Aaw-oHwAw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20to%20be%20doing%22&f=false))

I failed to analyse the bold part, and what does the part in italics mean? And what is the tense of the bold and italic parts? Or rather, why has such a tense been applied there?

Answer (score 3):

An **infinitive** can be a bare infinitive (e.g. *play*) or a to-infinitive (e.g. *to play*). There are also perfect and continuous forms.

**Example -**

> Kashmiri police also claim **to have found** Singh's involvement in five other cases of murder. [*Perfect form*]
>
> But they were strangers to her, and it was a vulgar thing **to be talking** about in the first place. [*Continuous form*]

In the above example sentences you must have noticed how perfect form and continuous form are achieved in infinitive clause.

**Infinitive clauses -** 
We can put an object or adverbial after the infinitive.

**Example -**

> I want ***to play** some records now*.

**The to-infinitive as subject and complement -**

**Example -**

> ***To break** your promise* would be wrong. [As a *subject*]
>
> It would be wrong ***to break** your promise*. [As a *complement*]
>
> The object of the game is ***to score** the most points*. [As *complement*]

<sub>**Reference -** Oxford Guide to English Grammar - John Eastwood. Example sentences are taken from Internet, and the notes beside example sentences inside '[...]' are written by me.</sub>

=========================================================================

Your sentence -

> **To be talking** about the dimensions of faithfulness as mediated by religious symbols is **to be doing** theology, not the practice itself.

This sentence contains two infinitive clauses -

- ***To be talking** about the dimensions of faithfulness as mediated by religious symbols*.
- ***to be doing** theology*.

Here in both the clauses, continuous aspect is achieved. Notice infinitive is still *un-tensed* - **to be**.

If X = ***To be talking** about the dimensions of faithfulness as mediated by religious symbols*.

and

Y = ***to be doing** theology*.

Your sentence takes the following form -

> X is Y (*, not the practice itself*.)

That actually means X = Y

The action of talking about the dimensions of faithfulness as mediated by religious symbols is the action of doing theology.